# UNIXドメインソケットのDGRAMにはデータ欠如などあり得るのでしょうか？

Tags: unix, socket

インターネットドメインソケットの場合
STREAM→コネクションが必要
DGRAM→コネクション不要
そのため、STREAMは信頼性のあるデータのやり取りができることに対し、
DGRAMはデータ欠如や順番の入れ替えなどがあり得るという認識です。

UNIXドメインソケットの場合なのですが、
UNIXドメインソケットはサーバ内のプロセス間での通信などに使い、
ポートを使用するのではなく、ファイルパスを使ってデータのやりとりができる認識でいます。

その場合、ネットワーク上でデータを送信しませんが、
DGRAMの場合、データ欠如などあり得るのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

仕様上は明記されてませんが、実際の実装ではSTREAMと同じように信頼でき、データ欠如などは無いものと考えてよいのだと思います。

> UNIX ドメインデータグラムサービスは信頼できます。メッセージを紛失したり異なった順序で配送することはありません。
>   —— 書籍『詳解UNIXプログラミング 第3版』の「17.2 UNIX ドメインソケット」より

---

> ほとんどの UNIX の実装では、 UNIX ドメインデータグラムソケットは常に信頼でき、 データグラムの並び替えは行わない
>   ——  Linux Programmer's Manual 「[UNIX](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man7/unix.7.html)」 より

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。リンク先大変参考になりました。